# change line width of dendrogram in pheatmap in R

Tags: pheatmap

I have used single cell RNA-seq data stored in a single cell experiment assay to perform hierarchical clustering of ~ 11.3000 expressed genes (not clustering samples) using pheatmap in R to show the heterogeneity of the data. I need the output image to be 2 x 4 inches, which makes the dendrogram a blur. Is it possible to reduce the line width used for the dendrogram?  I tried setting the line width by gpar, but it doesn't seem to change

sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
pheatmap_1.0.8

#### R code

```
gpar(lwd = 0.5)

pheatmap(assay(sce.tpm),  cellwidth = 10, cellheight= 0.009, fontsize = 5, 
fontsize_row = 6, fontsize_col = 6, 
scale = "row", cluster_cols = F, cluster_rows = T, 
clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean", clustering_method = "average"
color = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(256), 
show_colnames = T, show_rownames = F)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can directly manipulate the gtable object returned by the pheatmap call. Each grob has a `gp` parameter that is a `gpar` object.

```
library(pheatmap)
library(grid)

set.seed(42)
ph <- pheatmap(matrix(runif(100), nrow = 10), silent = TRUE)

ph$gtable$grobs[[1]]$gp <- gpar(lwd = 5)
ph$gtable$grobs[[2]]$gp <- gpar(col = 'blue')

png('pheatmap_gpar.png', height = 400, width = 400)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(ph$gtable)
dev.off()
```

It generates the following clustered heat map:

[image: pheatmap_dendrogram_adjust]