# Changing line width of dendrogram in heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I'm trying to plot a heatmap using `gplots::heatmap.2()` .There are a lot of rows and the dendrogram lines appear to be quite thin compared to the image. I 'm wondering if there is any technique to thicken the dendrogram lines as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469883/change-line-width-of-dendrogram-in-pheatmap-in-r) for the `pheatmap` output.
Thanks

Comment: The line `ph$gtable$grobs[[1]]$gp <- gpar(lwd = 5)` sets the line width.  It made the lines wide for me.

Comment: Thanks , but I'm looking for similar functionality in heatmap.2 function and NOT  in pheatmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `dendextend` package does this easily. We can use its `set()` function here to achieve the desired effect.

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10)

library(gplots)
library(dendextend)

dd <- set(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(dat))), "branches_lwd", 3)

heatmap.2(dat, Rowv = dd, Colv = dd)
```

[image]

It's worth looking into all the other cool stuff Dendextend does.